# Magento2: Class Mirasvit\Search\Model\Layer\FilterList\Interceptor generation error: The requested

Tags: magento2.3.7

Magento2: Class Mirasvit\Search\Model\Layer\FilterList\Interceptor generation error: The requested
I'm getting below error during compile command execution:

Interceptors generation... 4/8 [=============>------------] 50% 19 secs 324.0 MiB In Generator.php line 139:

Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\LayerCategoryConfig does not exist Class Mirasvit\Search\Model\Layer\FilterList\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only.

after running the bin/magento setup:di:compile CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write, the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method only.